# how does one restrict multiple generics arguments in C# dotnet

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

How do you "restrict" on 2 or more (multiple) placeholders?

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass<T> : ISomethingElse<T> where T : struct
{
}
```

Note, T is confined to a "struct", and I've done this several times over the years.

the above works fine

Now I want to create a generic class definition, and I want to put a constraint on T AND K.

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass<T, K> : ISomethingElse<T, K> where T : struct , K : struct
{
}
```

the above .. i cannot figure out the magic syntax sugar.

I know "easy".

Comment: The MSDN docs have an example. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Comment: Thanks asawyer, I missed this part of the how-to-KB https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#constraining-multiple-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict multiple generic arguments by including a `where` constraint for each argument separated by a space. So in your code snippet this would look like the following:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass<T, K> : ISomethingElse<T, K> where T : struct where K : struct
{
}
```

or a more readable version would be:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass<T, K> : ISomethingElse<T, K> 
  where T : struct 
  where K : struct
{
}
```

Comment: lol it always is, I also always have to look it up (I found your answer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes) ;)

Comment: b.t.w. @granadaCoder if one of the answers helped, it would be appreciated to mark it as the "Accepted Answer". This will help other people find the correct answer, informs other stack overflow users the question has been answered and of course rewards the giver of the answer the much sought after points ;).

Comment: I know the etiquette. :)  SOF locks you out for a bit !!  #justSayin'

Comment: Apologies I didn’t know that actually. Thanks for teaching me ;)

Comment: It must be somewhat new.  But yeah, there is "you cannot accept answer" for X minutes.  I don't recall the X minutes value.  Maybe to prevent ask/answer collusion with co-workers...I don't know.

Comment: BTW, there is also etiquette for upvoting a well defined question !  (#BAM !! )

Comment: Point well taken ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need the `where` keyword twice.

```
class Foo<T, K>
   where T : struct
   where K : struct
{
}
```

Those are constraints on type parameters, and the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) has a lot of useful information on them.